# Privilege drop: Allow readonly access to file for unprivileged process on a readonly file system

Tags: privileges, readonly, overlayfs

An ideally *least privileged* process should be able to have readonly access to data on a filesystem, which itself is readonly. Hence this is the situation

```
root@linux# ###(1) filesystem is untrusted + readonly
root@linux# grep untrusted_ro_fs /proc/mounts       
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/untrusted_ro_fs ext4 ro 0 0

root@linux# ###(2) no read permissions for (o)thers for /mnt/untrusted_ro_fs/root
root@linux# ls -ld /mnt/untrusted_ro_fs/root
drwxr-x--- 1 root root 1138 Jul  3 21:13 /mnt/untrusted_ro_fs/root

root@linux# ###(3a) unpriviledge process ls (run with uid=9999 and gid=9999) no read access
root@linux# setpriv --reuid=9999 --regid=9999 --clear-groups ls /mnt/untrusted_ro_fs/root
ls: cannot open directory '/root': Permission denied

root@linux# ###(3b) unpriviledge process cat (run with uid=9999 and gid=9999) no read access
root@linux# setpriv --reuid=9999 --regid=9999 --clear-groups cat /mnt/untrusted_ro_fs/root/file
cat: /mtn/untrusted_ro_fs/root/file: Permission denied

root@linux# ###(4) file permission change fails on ro filesystem
root@linux# chmod a+rx /mnt/untrusted_ro_fs/root/
chmod: changing permissions of '/mnt/untrusted_ro_fs/root/': Read-only file system
```

I seek answers how to accomplish above read access (3a + 3b). This are the pathways I have come up with. Ideally answers would either a) provide alternative solutions or b) elaborate on those provided:

- a) "daemon-style privelege drop": opening file-descriptors as root and subsequently `setuid` inside the process.
- b) "using FIFOs" which appears only to help with (3b)
  `root@linux# mkfifo /access_to_root_file.fifo`
  `root@linux# chown root:9999 /access_to_root_file.fifo`
  `root@linux# chmod 0640 /access_to_root_file.fifo`
  `root@linux# cat /mnt/untrusted_ro_fs/root/file > /access_to_root_file.fifo &`
  `root@linux# setpriv --reuid=9999 --regid=9999 --clear-groups cat /access_to_root_file.fifo`
- c) "overlayfs"
  `root@linux# mkdir /mnt/upper /mnt/work /mnt/merged`
  `root@linux# mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/mnt/untrusted_ro_fs,upperdir=/mnt/upper,workdir=/mnt/work /mnt/merged`
  `root@linux# chmod a+rx /mnt/merged/root`
  `root@linux# setpriv --reuid=9999 --regid=9999 --clear-groups ls /mnt/merged/root  &>/dev/null && echo SUCCESS-ls`
  `SUCCESS`
  `root@linux# chmod a+rx /mnt/merged/root/file`
  `root@linux# setpriv --reuid=9999 --regid=9999 --clear-groups cat /mnt/merged/root/file  &>/dev/null && echo SUCCESS-cat`
  `SUCCESS`
- d) "virtualization" (i.e. kvv + qemu)  where the readonly access to  blockdevice of untrusted filesystem is setup for the vm.

Answer (score 1):

The method that seems most natural to me is to create another view of the filesystem with different access rules, as in [Mount device with r/w access to specific user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30268/mount-device-with-r-w-access-to-specific-user). With [bindfs](https://bindfs.org/):

```
mkdir -m 700 /mnt/permissive_view
chown 9999:9999 /mnt/permissive_view
bindfs -r -M 9999 /mnt/untrusted_ro_fs /mnt/permissive_view
```

Then have 9999 access files under `/mnt/permissive_view`.

The option `-M 9999` causes user 9999 to see itself as the owner of all files. Depending on your exact use case, you may want different mappings, for example `-u 9999` (causes all users to see 9999 as the owner) or `--map=0/9999` (causes 9999 to be the apparenty owner of root-owned files only).

Comment: thank you for this suggestion, I am gald I asked the question, having overlooked this solution that is similar to overlayfs but in some way clearer.  With `bindfs` I have to wonder though, is it possible to have a "thumb-rule" for `bindfs` being [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) if this is a) "security" is FUSE already safer (not in kernel) or less rather less safe (added complexity) and b) is the general idead true that this solution comes at a cost of performance (user vs. kernel)?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace FUSE filesystems tend to be safer since the most delicate parts run in user mode, and so the worst that can happen is a user mode crash or compromise rather than a kernel crash or compromise. Bindfs doesn't really involve delicate parts though. FUSE does cost performance, only you can tell whether it matters in your case.